# xrdp on Ubuntu 14.04 blocking a single user

Tags: 14.04, xrdp

Looking for tips how to restore connection for a single user to xrdp remote desktop.

I've had some issues with the past at the working fix has been to clear all of the xrdp-related jobs from the user. After login the xrdp instantly shuts itself. I have tried the connection from windows and linux rdp with similar results.

I have also once restarted the service with no results.

The issue came out of nowhere and I know that it's not firewall related.

If it is any help, prior the problem the desktop of the remote machine had  disappeared, but you could still work there. After login out from the system, the connection could never been restored.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe there are orphaned sessions in /tmp/.X11-unix you need to manually remove.

Answer (score 1):

to be honest, your question is a little bit unclear.  If what you are looking for is to reconnect to the same session via xrdp,  the best options or recommendation I can give you are the following

- upgrade your system to Ubuntu 14.10 or later. This version has a new xrdp package that allow you to reconnect to existing session with no additional configuration (see info [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6046)
- try to find and install/upgrade the xrdp package version 0.6-1.x which allow you to reconnect to the same session
- perform a custom installation of xrdp. Using x11vnc with xrdp, you can achieve the same result i.e reconnecting to existing session (see [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5971) for instructions on how to perform a custom installation

Again, not sure about what your problem but hope this is helpful